# Changing value of a cell based on the value of two cells - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add some automation to a spreadsheet by changing the value of cells in one column based on the value in that column and one other. I have got the code below so far. If I use .text the code runs through fine but makes no changes to the values of the cells. If I use .value I get this error message:

Run-time error '13: Type mismatch

Please could someone advise on what I am doing wrong here.

```
Sub change_orrtime_4()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Each employee In Range("Timesheet_RawData[Employee]")

Dim employee As Range
Dim datefield As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tRows As Long
Dim tCols As Long
Dim i As Long



Set tbl = Sheets("Timesheet Data").ListObjects("Timesheet_RawData")


With tbl.DataBodyRange
    tRows = .Rows.Count
'    tCols = .Colummns.Count

End With


With Sheets("Timesheet Data")

Set employee = Sheets("Timesheet Data").Range("Timesheet_RawData[Employee]")
Set datefield = Sheets("Timesheet Data").Range("Timesheet_RawData[Date]")

End With

With Sheets("Timesheet Data")

For i = 2 To tRows


If employee.Value = "Some Name" And datefield.Value = "1" Then ' type mismatch doesnt occur with .text but then nothing works

employee.Value = "Some Name_SomeTeam"


End If

Next i

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're setting `employee` (and `datefield`, too) to multiple cells ranges, therefore you can't access it `Value` property, while you can access it `Text` property that would return a text if all cells share that same text or otherwise a `Null`

so you have to point at the specific cell in that range, like:

```
employee(i).Value
```

finally you could refactor your code a little as follows:

```
Sub change_orrtime_4()    
    Dim employee As Range
    Dim datefield As Range
    Dim tRows As Long
    Dim tCols As Long
    Dim i As Long


    With Sheets("Timesheet Data")
        With .ListObjects("Timesheet_RawData")
            With .DataBodyRange
                tRows = .Rows.Count
            '    tCols = .Colummns.Count
            End With
            Set employee = .ListColumns("Employee").DataBodyRange
            Set datefield = .ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange
        End With

        For i = 1 To tRows
            If employee(i).Value = "Some Name" And datefield(i).Value = "1" Then employee(i).Value = "Some Name_SomeTeam"
        Next i        
    End With        
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much! That worked perfectly - I have changed .ListColumns("Timesheet_RawData[Date]") to ("Date") as per the line above.

Comment: you're welcome. And you're right, too: I omitted that last change after having implemented it for "Employee" field. I'll edit the answer. thank you.